# jQueryUI draggable is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Why isn't jQueryUI draggable working in IE 8 for me? The strange thing is that resizable is working.

My Javascript code is following:

```
$(OBJ.cropProfileMiniatureRectangle)
    .draggable({ containment: OBJ.cropProfileMiniatureContainer })
    .resizable({
        handles: 'se', 
        aspectRatio: true, 
        minWidth: 100, 
        maxWidth: 445, 
        minHeight: 100, 
        maxHeight: 445, 
        containment: OBJ.cropProfileMiniatureContainer
    });
```

I have tried to change `$(OBJ.cropProfileMiniatureRectangle).draggable()` only, but still the same problem applies. But when I visit their [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), it is working. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't specify an object directly on the containment param.
From the example page:

> containment:
>   Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified
>   element or region. Possible string values: 'parent', 'document',
>   'window', [x1, y1, x2, y2].

**Edit:** I've tested in the demo page with the console and I was able to use a selector there by running: `$( "#draggable" ).draggable({containment:'#demo-frame'});`.

Can you post your HTML and CSS or a jsFiddle?